# Setting text at jQuery Mobile dialog doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I try to set a header and button texts dynamically via javascript. Unfortunattely it doesn't work as I thought. I added my text at jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/tMKD3/8/ .

HTML code:

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="start" data-theme="e">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="e">
      <h1 id="startHeader"></h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
      <a href="#page" id="buttonP1" onMouseUp="setup()" data-iconpos="right" data-role="button" data-prefetch data-mini="true"></a>
      <a href="#page" id="buttonP2" onMouseUp="setup()" data-iconpos="right" data-role="button" data-prefetch data-mini="true"></a>
      <a href="#page" id="buttonP3" onMouseUp="setup()" data-iconpos="right" data-role="button" data-prefetch data-mini="true"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Dialog -->
  <div data-role="dialog" id="dialog" data-theme="e">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e" data-position="fixed" data-close-btn="none">
       <h3 id="dialogHeader"></h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
      <a href="#start" type="button" data-role="button" id="dialogButton" data-rel="back"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // set button text
  $("buttonP1").text("Test");
  $("buttonP2").text("Test");
  $("buttonP3").text("Test");
}

function setup() {
  // set dialog header text
  $("dialogHeader").text("Dialog");
  $("dialogButton").text("Close");

  $.mobile.changePage('#dialog', {
      transition: 'pop',
      role: 'dialog'
  });
  return false;
}
```

Has somebody an idea what I did wrong and why it doesn't works?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Greetings, Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### change

```
$("dialogHeader").text("Dialog");
$("dialogButton").text("Close");
```

and

```
$("buttonP1").text("Test");
$("buttonP2").text("Test");
$("buttonP3").text("Test");
```

### to:

```
$("#dialogHeader").text("Dialog");
$("#dialogButton").text("Close");
```

and:

```
$("#buttonP1").text("Test");
$("#buttonP2").text("Test");
$("#buttonP3").text("Test");
```